# Does delaying blocks data receiving

Tags: c#, serial-port, delay, data-loss

I am working on a project on Visual Studio C#.

I am collecting data from a device connected to PC via serial port. 
First I send a request command, and wait for response.
There is a 1 sec delay of device to response after sending request command.
The thing is device may not be reached and may not response sometimes. 
In order to wait response (if any) and not to sent next data request command early, I make a delay by: System.Threading.Thread method.

My question is, if I make that delay time longer, do I loose serial port data receiving.

The Delay function I use is:

```
    private void Delay(byte WaitMiliSec)
    {
        // WaitTime here is increased by a WaitTimer ticking at every 100msec

        WaitTime = 0;
        while (WaitTime < WaitMiliSec)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't you use DataReceived event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx

Comment: No you are not going to lose serial port but i suggest you make thread.sleep less and check port connect or not if yes then call port for data otherwise put it in recursive function to call again and again if not connected and data not recieved.

Answer (score 2):

no - you won't loose any data - the serial-port has it's own buffer which does not depend on your application at all. The OS and the hardware will handle this for your.

I would suggest to refactor the data-send/receive into it's own task/thread. That way you don't need the `Application.DoEvents();`

If you post some more of your send/receive code I might help you with this.

PS: it seems to me that your code will not work anyhow (WaitTime is allways zero) but I guess it's just a snippet right?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I didn't get refactoring.

As I said, device may not response. So I made sending and receiving seperated. I send a command and wait 1 sec delay, then continue sending next command. If there is a return from device, it is captured via serialPort components own function named serialPort1_DataReceived. Received data is evaluated there.

By the way as you said the delay seems will not work but works.

Comment: refactoring just referes to changes in code that don't change the behaviour. I would put everything inside a thread/task, check for connection, send the command, wait till data is avaiable or time out and then receive/process the data or abort - everthing in a seperate thread so you don't block your UI.

Comment: I am learning to work with Threads. This may be a good training for me. I will definitely try. Thank you.